# list users who like page or url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I need to list users who like specific url or at least facebook page

I tried using both PHP and https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query

I can see the number of likers for the URL

```
$arr[1]['url'] = 'http://example.com/test/test3.php?ref=gametest&amp;fb_ref=gametest&amp;fb_source=gametest';
$arr[1]['object_id'] = '10150930574980642';

require_once("facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '325617367526193',
    'secret' => '6c40e01dd717431c9b7ec6ce68bf0c94',
));
```

I used http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/ example to form similar query

```
$query = <<<FQL
    SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="10150930574980642"
FQL;
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' . rawurlencode ( $query );
$fql_query_url .= '&access_token=' . rawurlencode ( $facebook->getAccessToken() );
```

but the resulting link gives no data at all

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

The same result via link with or without access_token

```
api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20user_id%20FROM%20like%20WHERE%20object_id%3D%2210150930574980642%22
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook: how to get all People who like a certain URL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7481259/facebook-how-to-get-all-people-who-like-a-certain-url)

Answer (score 1):

The "like" table will only return the IDs of users who like the following objects (video, note, link, photo, or album).

You cannot find out the user Ids of people who like a particular page, only objects within that page.

e.g. The likes for an album on the Facebook Page (SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="10150146071791729"&access_token=[access_token])

If you want to get the users that have liked a particular link, you will need to get the object_id of this link first:

[https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT url,site,id FROM object_url WHERE url IN ('http://developers.facebook.com')](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20url,site,id%20FROM%20object_url%20WHERE%20url%20IN%20%28%27http://developers.facebook.com%27%29)

This will return the object_id of the link http://developers.facebook.com.

Comment: actually I've already got the object ID for my particular link - it's
    $arr[1]['object_id'] = '10150930574980642';

Comment: @Aramaki so you should be able to run the query "SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id='10150930574980642'"  -  if 10150930574980642 is a valid link

Comment: this query returns empty {
  "data": [
  ]
} for all IDs I have (website inner page URL, website URL, facebook page). Looks like I need access_token. Do you know where to get access token for a FB Page which I admin?

Comment: Your ID doesn't seem to return a link. For example, if you try "/424010844310627" on the graph API Explorer it returns details of a link on the GuinnessIreland page. If I try it for your ID I get a return value of false "/10150930574980642". Can you tell us your pageId please? The permission you need is "read_stream" I think.